# Sabre seat map based on flight number

Tags: sabre

I am developing an app which will show live seat availability based on flight number using sabre apis.
https://developer.sabre.com/io-docs

I didnt find any way to do it.

Sabre needs marketing career details.

Is there any other way to get this using flight number only.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you want the seat map, this shows the available seats.
https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/rest_apis/air/search/seat_map

Keep in mind, that if prices are returned they are as extra, the price of the seat will depend on the class of service used at the time of booking. And there are some seats that, even if available, the airline blocks them. Maybe for latter use, preferred customers, to have them available at check in, or whatever reason they have.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer XML, the EnhancedSeatMap service will give you what you need:

https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_apis/air/book/seat_map

The marketing carrier is needed to uniquely identify the flight, since the same flight number may be offered by other carriers for the same origin and destination, and the same date.